# Filter orders by customer email id

Tags: sales-order, customer-attribute

How I can filter Magento order by any customer email id?
I'm doing  something like but I'm not getting the result.

```
$customer_email ='abc@gmail.com';
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email);
```

Comment: use addAttributeToFilter instead of addFieldToFilter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `addAttributeToFilter` instead of `addFieldToFilter` as in some case Sales model follow eav patten filter and select.

```
$customer_email ='abc@gmail.com';
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customer_email);
```

Comment: Starting version CE1.4 `addFieldToFilter` and `addAttributeToFilter` have the same effect. see `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract::addAttributeToFilter`.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the following code for filter the order collection with customer email it's working fine with my magento hope this will help you**

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$order_collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_email','abc@domain.com');
```